# How can i GET and POST global parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, get

How can i GET and POST GLOBAL parameter?

example:

```
    ViewBag.get = 2;

[HttpGet]/or/[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetString(string? getnumber)
    {
    ...////
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have global parameter in controller, but not in actions ? 
I am not sure I understand you, but the best way to do that is using session. Something like that: 
Set:
Session["Number"] = "2";

Get:
int number = (Session["Number"] != null) ? int.Parse(Session["Number"]) : -1;

I hope that helps, if not, specify your question :)

Comment: so i Used static Variable, but Thk for Answer!